# The L^p norms of matrix valued functions

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, operator-theory

What is the standard way to define the $L^p$ norm of a matrix valued function? Specific to my case I need to know
$\Vert M\Vert_{L^p(\mathbb{T}^3)},$
where $M$ is a 3 by 3 matrix, $\mathbb{T}^3$ is the 3 torus and $p\in [0,\infty]$.

Comment: I would say $\|M \|_{L^p}^p := \int_{T} |M(t)|dt$, where $|\cdot|$ is a matrix norm. You can use any norm here, matrix norms are all equivalent, and so the resulting $L^p$ norms are all equivalent.

Comment: Daw's comment is lacking a $p$-th power. It should be $\int_T |M(t)|^p\,dt$